# MySQL CHAR/VARCHAR won't store letters, but takes numbers just fine in my PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have been writing a script in PHP to take values from a form and store them in a MySQL table I created in the code, like this:

```
 mysql_query("CREATE TABLE `userdetails` ( userid VARCHAR(10), field1 CHAR(33), field2 CHAR(33), field3 VARCHAR(34)");
```

This only executes once, as I don't have access to the site's cPanel or phpMyAdmin, just the FTP server details. I collect strings from three text boxes, and then delete the current contents.

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM `userdetails` WHERE userid=$userid");
```

Next, I upload the strings to the MySQL server like this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `userdetails` (`userid`, `field1`, `field2`, `field3`) VALUES ($userid, $field1, $field2, $field3)")
```

With this script, I can get numbers to go on the database fine, but whenever I use a letter in the text box, it doesn't upload and the database field returns to NULL, I think.

From a little debugging, I can tell that the strings are storing the text box data fine, I can echo them and they display, with letters. It just doesn't upload. I have tried making a new table and trying again, that didn't work.

Comment: *"I collect strings from three text boxes"* - Quote your variables for your (string) values and [**use this**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).

Comment: @Jens `mysql_*` is deprecated use `mysqli_*` instead. Slight typo ;) Better yet... [**`mysqli_*` WITH prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) - `mysqli_` alone doesn't safeguard against SQL injection.

Comment: If the user exists already, you can always use `UPDATE` instead of `DELETE` and `INSERT`.

Answer (score 1):

You are vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, and are building an incorrect query.

Consider:

```
$userid = 'foo';
```

produces

```
mysql_query("DELETE .... WHERE user=foo");
```

You probably don't have a field named `foo` in your database, so the query fails. Since you obviously lack ANY kind of error handling, you'll never see the database spit your query back out at you with the syntax error highlighted.

At bare minimum, you need

```
mysql_query("DELETE ... WHERE user='$userid'"); // note the quotes
```

and some error handling

```
$result = mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());
```

And you really should go read http://bobby-tables.com before someone pwns your server via your badly written scripts.

Comment: I've pretty much given up pointing out that it's decrepit. Especially when pointing that out will just leave the OP no better off than before. "Don't shoot yourself in the head with a flintlock. It's obsolete. Use this AR-15"

Comment: Your second query does not close (") properly

Comment: You wrote `msyql_query` which should be `mysql_query` - typo.

Comment: no biggie. not as if any of my "queries" would actually run, anyways.